# error font coding, different input and output file

Tags: fonts, errors

I write coding at text maker not italic, why out put text italic ??

`\par Menurut hasil dari "\textit{Studi Teoretis Perubahan Trans-HCOH Menjadi H_{2}CO dan Trans-HCOH Menjadi HCOD Melalui quantum tunneling Dengan DFT dan Pendekatan WKB}" yang telah dilakukan oleh Rizka Nur Fadilla dan Nufida Dwi Aisyah. \textit{probabilitas quantum tunneling} menggunakan DFT dan WKB tidak sesuai dengan hasil eksperimen. Hasil tersbut dipelajari kembali oleh Maghfira Maulidiyah dengan menggunakan Fungsi Delta-Dirac untuk mendekati potensial sesungguhnya dan dibandingkan dengan hasil pendekatan WKB.
    \par Proposal Tugas Akhir ini mengusulkan untuk mempelajari penyelesaian \textit{quantum tunneling} dengan menggunakan persamaan Schr\"odinger.  Persamaan Schr\"odinger merupakan persamaan dinamika pada mekanika kuantum. Untuk menyelesaikan persamaan tersebut diperlukan potensial. potensial yang digunakan untuk mendekati potensial sesungguhnya yaitu \textit{rectagular potential}. Metode yang digunakan adalah \textit{coupled channel}.`

Answer (score 1):

The subscript operator `_` in `H_{2}CO` only works in math mode. TeX complains that is missing math mode:

```
! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text>
                $
```

As error recovery, TeX switches to math mode, that sets the text in math italics.

Solution: `H$_{2}$CO`

If there are more chemical formulas, then it can make sense to use a package for typesetting chemistry, e.g.:

```
\usepackage{mhchem}
...
\ce{H2CO}
```